# If I modify and include a MIT lcensed software in my website, have i to include the license?

Tags: licensing, mit

If i modify and include a MIT lcensed software in my website (script for functions, no download for users), have i to include the license? Have i to indicate the changes?

Answer (score 2):

What you do at home (in your websites' servers) is your business, nobody else's (MIT allows any use). If you distribute changed versions of the software, then the license kicks in.

Be careful if some of the code ends up running on the user's machine (i.e., Javascript snippets, applets of any sort), that is distribution.

Comment: Thanks Vonbrand, so if i use in my websites' servers i have not to include the license or the changes made, had i understand? Is this true even for GPL licenses?

Comment: @OrsoNeroツ, if you read the license carefully, it should become clear who is entitled to read the licence, disclaimers, and such: people reading the code, essentially, not users.